# Mathematica 2D limit computation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, limit, wolframalpha

Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica (on my laptop) give zero for the limit shown in the image below.

This is okay if x and y approach the origin along the path y = x.

But what happens if x and y approach the origin along the path y = x^3?

I have been unable to find any Stack Overflow questions that address this issue.

[image: Wolfram Alpha limit computation]

Comment: I'm voting to migrate this question to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Actually, I think this belongs on math.stackexchange.com.  It comes down to the fundamental issue of how you define a multi-variable limit.

Comment: Note that wolfram alpha correctly reports "limit does not exist or is path dependent.. " for this: `limit x*y / ( x^2+y^2 )  {x,y}->{0,0}`  (here the issue is the same except that the degenerate path is a line not a higher order curve.)

Comment: This is fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limits of a function f along path p depends on which path is taken. You hint at this in the question. If we insert y=x^3 into f, we get the constant 1/2. So the limit of f towards (0,0) along the path y=x^3 is 1/2.

Mathematica only computes limits along a one axis at a time. Even thought WolframAlpha makes it look like it knows how to compute the correct (x,y)->(0,0) it actually computes lim x->0 lim y->0 f(x,y).

This question and answer can be used to examine the situation graphically:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21549/11860

Comment: Thanks soegaard. Part of my aim was to highlight the fact that these applications can sometimes be too bold. A pair of axis-defined paths is clearly insufficient to cover the requirement that all 1D limits on all paths be the same. The other part was to learn how the erroneous computation was done (what assumptions were in play etc.). Perhaps the axis path constraint is mentioned in the documentation, but that doesn't excuse an unambiguous output of zero for this computation.

Comment: @svenpables In all fairness, *mathematica* doesn't do a multi variable `Limit` at all ( For just this reason I'd assume ), so your criticism applies only to wolfram alpha.

Comment: @agentp, Mathematica gives the same result for Limit[x^3*y/(x^6+y^2),{x,y}->{0,0}], namely zero. I accept that the informed user might know that this merely means the limits on each of the axis paths are equal and zero. But as far as I can tell, the application makes no such qualification. Thus, the unqualified result computed by Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica is false.

Comment: That multivariable usage is not documented and gives an error:  "{x,y} is not a valid variable" (mathematica v10.1.).  I'm guessing you are invoking wolfram alpha within mathematica ( orange  `=` at the beginning of the line..)

Comment: Apologies @agentp. I misremembered the syntax. The command Limit[x^3*y/(x^6+y^2),{x->0,y->0}] works in Mathematica but the result is {0,0} (meaning that the limit is being calculated separately along each axis).

Comment: That is false now. It calculates both limit over x over y and over y over x since some version and if those are equal... Alpha is also fixed now.